# ls: single-column vs. multi-column layout, non-Unicode characters in filenames

Tags: ls, macos, unicode, bugs

Create a directory `~/test` with `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` and `zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba` files in it.

`ls ~/test` will list them using multi-column layout:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
```

Each filename is 26 characters long.

But if you use Cyrillic letters, the maximum length of a filename for `ls` to use multi-column layout is limited to 17 characters. If any of your filenames is longer, the single-column layout will be used. Is it documented somewhere? Or is it just a bug?

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz      абвгдеёжзийклмноп
```

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
абвгдеёжзийклмнопр
```

Comment: I suspect some additional testing or reading of the source might be necessary to be certain, but I conjecture: (a) There is no hard limit on the length. `ls` to a terminal columnises the names taking the width of the terminal window into account. I can multicolumn an 80-byte name in a 150-wide window. (b) The length of names is measured in bytes, with no accounting for the fact that multi-byte characters only occupy one display position.

Comment: Is this on macOS?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, macOS 14.3, zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0). But I suspect this might me not only macOS issue.

Comment: @jsx97 GNU `ls` on Linux handles this correctly; macOS has its own implementation of `ls`, which might or might not account for multi-byte characters, and its normalisation defaults decompose many characters, which adds to the fun, so it could well be macOS-specific.

Comment: @StephenKitt Could you suggest where to read about maOS implementation of ls? man ls doesn't seem to mention this behavior.

Comment: @jsx97 I get the impression the implementation [is this one](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/file_cmds/tree/f8c84000d1f02be159053846a3d730b0290f9614/ls), but that might not be particularly useful.